# MYSQL limiting data returned by category

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have a MYSQL table like this:

```
    create table service
(
    id int(12) not null auto_increment,
    name varchar(300) not null,
    address varchar(300),
    suburb varchar(300),
    postcode varchar(10),
    phone varchar(14),
    latitude float(25,20),
    longitude float(25,20),
    description varchar(300),
    service_type varchar(300) not null,
    primary key (id)
);
```

This table contains a series of services of various kinds. When I retrieve services from this list it is done so by location, so I can't guarantee which services will be returned. The location is roughly a 3 km radius. In order to account for formatting on the web page we are displaying the results on we are limiting the results returned to 5 rows. I have encountered an issue where, because of the data in the table, the rows returned all happen to be of the same service_type. It is not advantageous to me to return 5 gyms that happen to be in the area while ignoring other services. Is there a way to limit the results returned to be a maximum of one or two for any particular service_type?

Here is some output from the table in an array returned by json from php:

```
[Array[10], Array[10], Array[10], Array[10], Array[10]]
0:Array[10]
0:"7780"
1:"Ardrie Park Tennis Club"
2:"64 Ardrie Street "
3:"EAST MALVERN"
4:"3145"
5:""
6:"-37.87911224365234400000"
7:"145.05429077148438000000"
8:""
9:"Sports"
length:10
__proto__:Array[0]
1: Array[10]
0: "7783"
1:"Easterverne Tennis Club"
2:"91 Manning Road "
3:"EAST MALVERN"
4:"3145"
5: ""
6:"-37.87286758422851600000"
7:
"145.05358886718750000000"
8:""
9:"Sports"
length:10
__proto__ : Array[0]
2:Array[10]
0:"7791"
1:"Penpraze Park"
2:"10 Victoria Road South "
3:"EAST MALVERN"
4:"3145"
5:""
6:"-37.87079620361328000000"
7:"145.03793334960938000000"
8:""
9 :"Sports"
length:10
__proto__:
Array[0]
3:Array[10]
4:Array[10]
length:5
__proto__:Array[0]
```

Here is the query that generated it:

```
$query = "SELECT s.id,s.name,s.address,s.suburb,s.postcode,s.phone,s.latitude,s.longitude,s.description,s.service_type "
        . "FROM service s, emotion_service es, emotion e, service_type st, active a, social so "
        . "where s.latitude < '$latLng[0]' and s.latitude > '$latLng[1]' "
        . "and s.longitude < '$latLng[2]' and s.longitude > '$latLng[3]' "
        . "and e.name = 'sad' "
        . "and e.id = es.emotion_id "
        . "and es.service_id = s.id "
        . "and s.id = st.service_id "
        . "and st.active_id = a.id "
        . "and st.social_id = so.id "
        . "and a.name = '$active' "
        . "and so.name = '$social' "
        //. "GROUP BY s.service_type ";
        . "LIMIT 5";
```

Also group by removes most of the results returned for some reason. It doesn't limit it to one row per service type, it only returns 1 row.

Comment: For the sake of better understanding sample input and expected output would suffice. Also add your current query.

Comment: Sometimes it's very clever to simply use the search function: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql+n+results+per+group

Answer (score 0):

To get only one result per service_type you can use "GROUP BY":

```
SELECT service_type, MAX(ID)
FROM table
WHERE latitude = xxxx and longitude = xxxx
GROUP BY service_type
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very clear, but if i understood correctly following can randomize the result set and same can be used as offset

```
$offsetRes = mysql_query( " SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * COUNT(*)) AS `offset` FROM `yourtable` ");
```

$offset_row = mysql_fetch_object( $offsetRes); 
$offsetVal = $offset_row->offset;
$result = mysql_query( " SELECT * FROM `yourtable` LIMIT $offset, 1 " );